# Use result from table_schema query as <table> in select * from <table>

Tags: postgresql, information-schema

Is it possible in PostgreSQL to use the result of the query below as table name in a SELECT * FROM .

```
SELECT table_name
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_name LIKE 'seam_event_%'
ORDER BY table_name DESC
LIMIT limit 1
```

The current database is using table partitioning. 90% of the time we only search the last two partition tables. Therefor we would like to create a view with the records of the last 2 partition tables.

I tried the following:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT table_name
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_name LIKE 'seam_event_%'
    ORDER BY table_name DESC
    LIMIT 1) AS a
UNION
SELECT * FROM (SELECT table_name
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_name LIKE 'seam_event_%'
    ORDER BY table_name DESC
    LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1) AS b
```

Unfortunatly, this is returning:

```
table_name
______________
seam_event_74
seam_event_75
```

Bottom line, which is the best way to query the last two partition tables and how to achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Regards,

Bas

---------- EDIT ----------

I've tried to create a functions that will return the results of the last two child tables. But i keep getting a syntax error.

**Function:**

```
DROP FUNCTION select_from_table();

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION select_from_table()
  RETURNS SETOF seam_event AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    TABLE_VAR1 varchar;
    TABLE_VAR2 varchar;
BEGIN
    select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_name like 'seam_event_%' order by table_name desc limit 1 INTO TABLE_VAR1;
    select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_name like 'seam_event_%' order by table_name desc limit 1 offset 1 INTO TABLE_VAR2;

    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM ' || TABLE_VAR1;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
  COST 100;

SELECT * FROM select_from_table();
```

**ERROR:**

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'SELECT * FROM '"
LINE 1:  EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM ' ||  $1 
                 ^
QUERY:   EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM ' ||  $1 
CONTEXT:  SQL statement in PL/PgSQL function "select_from_table" near line 8

********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "'SELECT * FROM '"
SQL state: 42601
Context: SQL statement in PL/PgSQL function "select_from_table" near line 8
```

Comment: That error cannot come from the code above if I'm not mistaken (I tried it actually and it worked).

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this with ordinary SQL, at least in PostgreSQL. You need to use PL/PgSQL to generate dynamic SQL and run it with `EXECUTE`. The

```
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format('SELECT ... FROM %I WHERE $1, $2', tablename) USING param1, param2;
```

construct is useful.

See [executing dynamic statements](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN).

Comment: tried your suggestion but no luck. Can you please assist met by getting my function right.;

Comment: @user153689 What PostgreSQL version are you on? Maybe you're on an old version before `return query` supported `execute`?

Comment: "PostgreSQL 8.3.7 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 3.4.6 20060404 (Red Hat 3.4.6-10)"

Comment: @user153689 upgrade your PostGreSQL. As 8.3.7 was release the 19th of March 2009.. However this does not explain your QUERY EXECUTE issue. as this was supported as of 2008 ( See this maillist post http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/162867790804050503p5af491d2ga3dc17de7a96c0dd@mail.gmail.com ( dated 5th of April 2008 ) )